# VPS with Debian Squeeze cannot forwward email - Name service error for name=gmail.com type=MX: Host not found, try again

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, postfix, debian-squeeze, mx-record

I have postfix set-up on my Debian VPS, I can:

- send emails
- receive emails

on my server

But forwarding emails from my server to gmail does not work!

I configured google's DNS through /etc/resolv.conf

I can ping google.com and with dig I also find gmail MX records. But when my server tries to forward email to gmail (setup with /etc/aliases) I get the following error:

```
postfix/smtp[20280]: 825E117BA8A80: to=<john_doe@gmail.com>, orig_to=<xxx@xxx.yyy>, relay=none, delay=40, delays=0/0.01/40/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=gmail.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
```

What am I missing? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have to modify resolv.conf?

Answer (score 4):

You are almost certainly running with postfix chrooted.  You need to copy /etc/resolv.conf into the chroot as well.  On Debian that should be /var/spool/postfix/ - so /var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf.

You may want to check that you don't have SYNC_CHROOT turned off in /etc/default/postfix - it default's to yes - so just stopping and starting postfix with the init script should copy the new /etc/resolv.conf into the right location:

/etc/init.d/postfix stop
/etc/init.d/postfix start

You can check if you are running chrooted by looking for any 'y' in the chroot column in /etc/postfix/master.cf

Comment: This happened to me because I was running postfix inside docker. The `/var/spool/postfix/etc/` directory didn't exists, so I created it and copied the `resolv.conf` there. After that, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your name resolution setup is broken. Repair it. First have a look into `/etc/resolv.conf`.